# Rails Controller Spec. Wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test my controller using RSpec but I'm getting the error below.

#### error

```
  1) Api::V1::UsersController GET #show responds with 200 status code
     Failure/Error: request.headers.merge!(auth_headers)

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Api::V1::UsersController GET #show returns the serialized user attributes
     Failure/Error: request.headers.merge!(auth_headers)

     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)
     # ./spec/controllers/api/v1/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

#### spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :api do

  describe 'GET #show' do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryBot.create :user
      auth_headers = @user.create_new_auth_token
      request.headers.merge!(auth_headers)
      get :show, id: @user.id
    end

    it 'responds with 200 status code' do
      expect(response.code).to eq('200')
    end

    it 'returns the serialized user attributes' do
      expect(json['data']['attributes']).to eq({'name'=>'John Doe', 'email'=>'test@test.com'})
    end
  end

end
```

#### spec_helper

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}


RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ApiHelper, type: :api
  config.include Requests::JsonHelpers, type: :api

  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end
  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

#### api_helper.rb

```
module ApiHelper
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    Rails.application
  end
end
```

#### request_helper.rb

```
module Requests
  module JsonHelpers
    def json
      JSON.parse(last_response.body)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the full error message, where does the error comes from?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma `get :show, id: @user.id`

Comment: try to debug `auth_headers`

Comment: @LiroyLeshed.com `{"access-token"=>"Fb1PMNcGsW-eLN3idl0j2A", "token-type"=>"Bearer", "client"=>"YQtnU5BsYz9GX5VO1MJp_A", "expiry"=>"1510965716", "uid"=>"jailyn@king.co"}`

Comment: Can't figure it out yet, but won't it be easier to test it by simply using `type: :controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :api`

must be

`describe Api::V1::UsersController, type: :controller`

**OR** (and it will be more suitable for api test)

you can rewrite this

```
auth_headers = @user.create_new_auth_token
request.headers.merge!(auth_headers)
get :show, id: @user.id
```

to this

```
auth_headers = { 'AUTHORIZATION' => "Token #{@user.create_new_auth_token}" }
get :show, { id: @user.id }, auth_headers
```